# JSON: Массив [] или массив {}?

Tags: javascript, массивы, json

В общем, есть пустой массив array[]. В его значение я добавлял массив xray таким образом:

```
array[array.length] = xray;
```

Казалось бы, все хорошо, но когда кодируешь этот массив в JSON - пустота.

Проблему решил при помощи:

```
var temp = {};
temp.title = xray['title'];
temp.value = xray['value'];
array[array.length] = temp;
```

И при JSON.stringify(array) получил корректный результат.

Вопрос один: почему так? Чем JSON.stringify не устроил первый вариант?

Comment: добавлю, что xray создавался квадратными скобками

Answer (score 3):

Потому что JSON-представление массива, созданного как `xray = [];` - это его элементы, разделенные запятыми, в квадратных скобках.

```js
var array = [];
var temp = [];
temp[0] = 'test';
temp.title = 'title'; //не будет включенo в JSON массива temp
array[array.length] = temp;
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Comment: Аааа. Я правильно понял, что массив с квадратными скобками не будет включен в JSON потому, что JSON сам использует квадратные скобки?

Comment: @МирейАров нет, неправильно. Посмотрите измененный пример.